# What is the best way to rewrite a given code into a function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ujs

I need to automatically rewrite a link that triggers a function (written on the fly) and convert it into unobtrusive JavaScript code.

Example:

```ruby
link_to_function 'hey', "alert('hey')"
```

becomes:

```html
<a href='#' onclick="alert('hey')"> hey </a>
```

My idea is make a reference in the HTML element and create an object in JS to store all the related code. Then convert the former example in a cleaner and unobtrusive
example:

```html
<a href='#' data-href='rndReference'> hey </a>
```

and in JS (the `code` variable is the JS code that I have stripped out from the markup):

```js
storageCode[rndReference] = new Function(code)
```

Each string of code is passed through a new `Function(code)` in order to call it as a function.

What is wrong in this approach? What approach would be better?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the normal way this is done.

```html
<a href='#' onclick="alert('hey')"> hey </a>
```

becomes:

```html
<a href='#' data-role='alert'> hey </a>
```

Then in a [CoffeeScript](http://coffeescript.org/) file:

```coffee
$ ->
  $("a[data-role='alert']").on("click", (event) ->
    event.preventDefault()
    alert("hey")
  )
```

or, if you don’t like CoffeeScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("a[data-role='alert']").on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert("hey");
  });
)
```

Comment: That's the normal way. I'm asking how about running random code? the idea is passing through a helper. and replace the link_to_function, with [link_to_ujs](http://www.github.com/gagoar/link_to_ujs)

Comment: link_to_ujs is obviously not "unobtrusive javascript" -- it is obtrusive and runs on the onclick event of a links. If this works for you, go for it.

Comment: link_to_ujs puts the code in a JavaScript  object and a data-ref in the markup with a code to bind that data-ref. it's ujs all the way. It is exactly like the example in the question. the second one

Comment: @gagoar ok, I see that now. Recommend you remove the comments, since they're not in sync with your code. Regarding your approach: to each their own... if it works for you, go for it.